# Reading/Writing Process Memory in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to read and write values from memory addresses in a given already running program, similar to Cheat Engine.

So far, I tried the solution provided in the following link: https://codingvision.net/c-read-write-another-process-memory#2read-process-memory

In case the link is dead, here was the code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class MemoryRead
{
    const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    public static void Main()
    {

        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0]; 
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id); 

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[24]; //'Hello World!' takes 12*2 bytes because of Unicode 

        // 0x0046A3B8 is the address where I found the string, replace it with what you found
        ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0x0046A3B8, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer) + " (" + bytesRead.ToString() + "bytes)");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error

***System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Retrieving information about local processes is not supported on this platform.'***

on the line:

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
```

Does anyone know what can be done here? Is there an alternative solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Which call are you getting the issue on, also its less than optimal to refer to an offsite resource to show your code. What if that site disappears? Your question becomes worthless to future readers

Comment: @TheGeneral I edited the original post to be more clear, and included the code from the source. Sorry, this is my first post!

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670590/process-getprocessesbyname-dont-work-with-uwp

Comment: I saw that thread. I can't figure out what he means by "You need to run with App Diagnostics capability".

Comment: I won't be surprised if you can't do that in UWP apps. UWP has too much limitations when accessing system information. I'd say a possbile way is to do this in a win32 app and package it via desktop bridge.

Comment: I spoke with someone about this, and yeah. Apparently starting mostly with Windows 8, they've been trying to give every program their own little garden to section themselves off. 

Welp, any suggestions what I should learn to do this? I'm not sure what you mean by doing this in a "win32 app and package it via desktop bridge."